# How to have One UIViewController with multiple interfaces

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface, protocols

I know in Java it is possible to have a class that contains no public interface.  Instead the developer places any public properties and methods in an Interface class that is implemented by the other class.  So my question is:

Is it possible to have a UIViewController that has interface classes that expose different methods?  In Objective C, an interface class would be a protocol, no?  Is there a way to force a protocol to be the UIViewController's interface?  I mean like this:

```
UIViewController contains methods:
    - (void)methodA 
    - (void)methodB 
    - (void)methodC 
    - (void)methodD 
    - (void)methodE

Protocol A contains methods:
    - (void)methodA 
    - (void)methodB 

Protocol B contains methods:
    - (void)methodC 
    - (void)methodD 
    - (void)methodE

Protocol C contains methods:
    - (void)methodA 
    - (void)methodB 
    - (void)methodE
```

I want to use the same UIViewController, but I want it to expose different methods and properties based on the application in which it is being used.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Lets say you are creating several applications that do pretty much the same thing and you're making your applications available to users as an SDK.  You want to provide some "extra" functionality to some customers but not to others.  The idea is (if the differences are so minute) not to maintain code in two different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what protocols / delegates are used for.  Implement the protocol on your viewcontroller then set datasource / delegates on the class that will call those methods.  For example:

```
@protocol delegateA <NSObject>
    - (void)methodA 
    - (void)methodB 
@end

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <delegateA>
//Implement protocol methods here
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<delegateA> delegate;
@end
```

Now in your `MyClass` class you can call methods upon your viewcontroller after setting the view controller to be that new classes delegate and calling it like so

`[self.delegate methodA]`

but you can only call methods declared within `delegateA`, not the entire interface of your view controller class.

Comment: Thank you.  I am very weak in the area of protocols and delegates.  Still struggling with them.  I thought this was possible but wanted confirmation from a veteran.  Thanks again.